# How can I open bootstrap modal on select box option change?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which is submitted on option change. It is connected to the database. So everytime I submit the form, the page reloads and the value is selected (the value is now saved as "car" in the database).

```
<form class="cars" id="carSelect" name="car" action="index.php" method="get">
 <select onchange='this.form.submit()'>
  <option <?php if ($row['car'] == Volvo ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option <?php if ($row['car'] == Saab ) echo 'selected'; ?>  value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option <?php if ($row['car'] == Opel ) echo 'selected'; ?>  value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option <?php if ($row['car'] == Audi ) echo 'selected'; ?> value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select> 
</form>
```

when the form is submitted and the selected option is `Volvo`, a modal (I am using the bootstrap modal) should appear. This is the bootstrap modal code, which opens the modal when I click on the "openBtn" Button.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="openBtn">Volvo</a>

<div id="modal-content" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>Volvo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" id="txtname" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"> 
                <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</a>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The bootstrap modal script for opening the modal with a button:

```
$('#openBtn').click(function () {
    $('#modal-content').modal({
        show: true
    });
});
```

**So here is my approach**:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($(.cars option:Volvo).is(':selected')){
        $('#modal-content').modal({
            show: true
        });
    }
});
```

But my code is not working. The other problem is, the modal should only appear if I selected "Volvo". Not everytime the page is loaded. But I do not know how I can detect that the form was submitted before the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the correct solution that you have been waiting for.
Please look at this code :

```js
function myFunction() {
    var option_value = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
    if (option_value == "3") {
        alert("Hai !");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
// Add the above javascript code here !
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id = "numbers" onchange = "myFunction()">
<option value = "1">1</option>
<option value = "2">2</option>
<option value = "3">Click me !</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you want the selected option you have to take it from the select `DOM` element. So you would start with giving it an ID.

```
 <select onchange='this.form.submit()' id="carSelect">
```

Then you can get the currently selected value and use it as condition.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var value = $( "#carSelect option:selected").val();
    if(value == 'volvo'){
        $('#modal-content').modal({
            show: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, this is working well. I still have one problem. Everytime I load the page now the modal is appearing. But it should only appear after I changed the option for the first time to "volvo"

Comment: when the option is changed, then the form is submitted and if then "Volvo" is selected, open the modal. But not if I do no option change and only load the page.

Comment: This will only work, when you trigger it on "change" event. But this will not work when submitting the form on the same event. You could submit the form via ajax to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select onchange='funMyModel(this.value)'>

function funMyModel(val)
{
    if(val=="Volvo"){
        $('#modal-content').modal({
            show: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is not working. I forgot to say, that I have 3 froms which look the same on this page

Comment: Hi I added an id to my form like Horsch Nok suggested. So now it is working. But my problem is now that the modal appears everytime when I load my page, not only if I changed the option to "Volvo"

Comment: Thank you, but I need `onchange='this.form.submit()'` because by every option change I save the value in the SQL database

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check the selected value in select option. Select adds the :selected property to the selected option which is a child of the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#select").on('change', function(){        
        if($(this).find(":selected").val()=='xyz'){
            //alert($(this).find(":selected").val());
            $('#modal-content').modal({
                show: true
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but for those who may find it like I did, I wanted to share a small adaptation I did, so if I have one modal per select option, I don't need to check every and each of the possibilities:

```php
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#myModalSelector").on('change', function(){ 
        var selected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        $('#' + selected ).modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: cool but it will be better to show the full code including the modal